# JS's Number vs ECMAScript's ToNumber methods

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is the [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) method of javascript the direct implementation of [ToNumber](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3) method defined in ECMAScript?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Specifications

Comment: `Number` is not a method but an Object

Comment: @Weedoze How does that help answer OP's question? `Number` is not a method, as you say, but it is a function, and their question certainly pertains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `Number` function returns the result of ToNumber, with the added behavior that if no argument is given, 0 is returned.

We can find out how built-in functions like Number behave in section 15 of the spec, "Standard Built-in ECMAScript Objects." There, under ["15.7 Number Objects"](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.7) we find:

> ### 15.7.1 The Number Constructor Called as a Function
>
> When **`Number`** is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it performs a type conversion.
>
> #### 15.7.1.1 Number ( [ value ] )
>
> Returns a Number value (not a Number object) computed by [ToNumber](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3)(*value*) if *value* was supplied, else returns **+0**.